# shell script to filter records in a zip file that contains matching columns from another file

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, sed

Not sure if this is the correct forum for this question. I have two files. file1.zip, file2

**Input:**

```
file1.zip
col1    col2    col3
a       b   0:0:0:0:0:c436:9346:d40b
x       y   0:0:0:0:0:880:39f9:c9a7
m       n   0:0:0:0:0:80c7:9161:fe00

file2.txt
col1
c4:36:93:46:d4:0b
08:80:39:f9:c9:a7
48:1d:60:62:f5:9d
```

I need to

- Convert col3 in file1 to col1 in file2 format i.e., ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl
  by padding 0's for and using semicolon':' for every 2 characters
  after trimming first 10 char.
- compare it with col1 in table B and   store the matching columns

**required output for the above scenario**

```
col1    col2    col3
a       b   c4:36:93:46:d4:0b
x       y   08:80:39:f9:c9:a7
```

I have 1500 zip files and one reference file. Not sure how to achieve this in unix. Can someone please help.

for direct files, I used

```
ls *.zip | awk '{ print "zipgrep -f file2.txt "$0" >> result.csv"}' | xargs -I {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the cleaned up address in a variable and `grep -q` to see it is present in the first column of file2 using process substitution.

**Updated:**

```
header="" && IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(zcat -Szip file1.txt.zip); do 
[[ -z "$header" ]] && header="$a" && echo "$header" >> results.txt && continue 
addr=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$a" | sed 's/0:0:0:0:0://;s/\([^:][^:]\)\([^:][^:]\)/\1:\2/g;s/\([^:]\)\([^:][^:]\)/0\1:\2/g')
read -d'\n' col1 col2 < <(awk '{printf $1"\n"$2}' <<< "$a") 
for b in file[^1].txt.zip; do 
 zgrep -q "$addr" <(awk '{print $1}' <(zcat -Szip "$b")) && echo "${col1} ${col2} ${addr}" >> results.txt; 
done  
done
```

The code echoes out the first line as the header and the subsequent matches are echoed thereafter, column one and two from the first file, and the cleaned up and matched address from column three in the first file.

Comment: Thank you @A,Danishewski, Can we leverage zipgrep here or just unzip all the files and then perform this in loop? file1.txt here would be a zip something like file1.zip and I have 1500 similar zip files in the directory. Can we run this without unzipping (to save space on the disk)

Comment: You can use `zcat` on the ref file `E.g. $(< file1.txt) to $(zcat -Szip file1.zip)`. Then wrap the `grep -q` part with a `for loop` to loop over the zips, change `grep -q` to `zgrep -q` and write the results out (concatenating it from the loop `>>`).

Comment: This is not working @A.Danischewski. Its pulling up everything in file 1

Comment: I updated my answer to use `zcat` and `zgrep`. I forgot to mention that you have to update the `awk` looking at the first column if you are using `zcat`.

Comment: Thanks you for all the efforts  @A.Danischewski.. But where do I put the reference file file 2? I'm sorry for being so naive

Comment: The code I put is only for an example, it presumes the same directory for all zips and only handles single digits. The first file is presumed to be the reference file as you have it in the question. The subsequent zip files are in the same directory starting with file2.txt.zip and on. But the way it's coded it will only take files 2-9 (you have to change the `file[^1].txt.zip` part of the code to match the files you want, I put that only for a quick test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98151/discussion-between-anil-and-a-danischewski).

Comment: So. let me explain it one more time 
I have a set if zip files. example file1.zip - file1500.zip. I can easily read them from ls 
I have a reference file. let it be reference.txt which just have one column. 
I need to match the column in reference file to all the zip files (say column 3) 
So should I use the following command

Comment: header="" && IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(cat reference.txt); do 
[[ -z "$header" ]] && header="$a" && echo "$header" >> results.txt && continue 
addr=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$a" | sed 's/0:0:0:0:0://;s/\([^:][^:]\)\([^:][^:]\)/\1:\2/g;s/\([^:]\)\([^:][^:]\)/0\1:\2/g') 
read -d'\n' col1 col2 < <(awk '{printf $1"\n"$2}' <<< "$a") 
for b in file[^1].txt.zip; do 
zgrep -q "$addr" <(awk '{print $1}' <(zcat -Szip "$b")) && echo "${col1} ${col2} ${addr}" >> results.txt; 
done 
done

Comment: You seem to want the reverse of the reference file above, just change it around except that now you are looping over all the zip files, I presume they each have a column header so I've added another line to skip the first line after the first  column header is written.

Comment: `header="" && IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in *.zip; do 
line1=1 && for b in $(zcat -Szip "$a"); do 
[[ -z "$header" ]] && header="$b" && echo "$header" >> results.txt && line1=0 && continue; 
(($line1)) && line1=0 && continue; 
addr=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$b" | sed 's/0:0:0:0:0://;s/\([^:][^:]\)\([^:][^:]\)/\1:\2/g;s/\([^:]\)\([^:][^:]\)/0\1:\2‌​/g'); 
read -d'\n' col1 col2 < <(awk '{printf $1"\n"$2}' <<< "$b"); 
zgrep -q "$addr" <(awk '{print $1}' reference.txt) && echo "${col1} ${col2} ${addr}" >> results.txt; 
done;  
done`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=file1.txt
FILE2=file2.txt

awk -v dict="$FILE2" '
  function pad(x, padding) {
    if (length(x) >= 1+length(padding)) {return x};
    return substr(padding x, length(x));
  }
  BEGIN { while ( getline < dict ) { keep[$1]=$1 }}
  NR==1 {print; next}  # print the header
  {s = substr($3,11); n=split(s,a,":"); 
   ans="";
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { 
     a[i] = pad(a[i], "000"); 
     ans = ans (ans==""?"":":") substr(a[i],1,2) ":" substr(a[i],3);
   }
   if (keep[ans]) { $3=ans; print }
  }' "$FILE1"
```

Since you indicated you have just one reference file, I'd unzip it to a (presumably) temporary file; each of the other files can be unzipped "on the fly".  So instead of 'awk ... "$FILE1"' above, you could put it in a loop, *along the lines of*:

```
ls *.zip | while read FILE1 ; do unzip -p "$FILE1" | awk ... ; done
```

Comment: Thank you @peak, Can we leverage zipgrep here or just unzip all the files and then perform this in loop? FILE1 here would be a zip something like file1.zip and I have 1500 similar zip files in the directory. Can we run this without unzipping (to save space on the disk)

Comment: @anil -- I did say "along the lines of".  Did you use the -p option of unzip, or did you use zcat?  If you aren't specific about what you did and what error messages you had, you are giving the impression that you need to read up on the tools you're trying to use.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I copied the script in to a file and replaced FILE1 and FILE2 with my files. I've not tested them on zip files. thought if this works on regular files, I could extend it for all the zip files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 
    'NR==FNR{t=$0;gsub(":","");a[$0]=t;next} 
      FNR==1; 
       FNR>1{v=""; 
             n=split($3,b,":"); 
             for(i=n-2;i<=n;i++) 
                v=v sprintf("%04s",b[i]); 
            } 
      v in a{print $1,$2,a[v]}' file2 file1

col1    col2    col3
a       b       c4:36:93:46:d4:0b
x       y       08:80:39:f9:c9:a7
```